# How can I write sth into the Page TS Config in Typo3 v 9.5? It is not editable for some reason

Tags: apache, typo3, config, admin, backend

I had a new setup of Typo3 version 9.5 with composer and localhost apache. Everything seemed fine. Then I wanted to add the "allowed CE" into the PageTSConfig panel, since I wanted to only allow text elements for a certain backend layout column. But then I realised I couldn't add anything into that page ts config panel.
Does anyone know why that is? I am the only backend user, and I am the admin.

I tried to use the user config panel but that didn't work at all.

**EDIT 1:**
Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.5.5",
        "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5",
        "algo26-matthias/idna-convert": "^3.0",
        "gridelementsteam/gridelements": "^9.1"
    },
    "scripts":{
        "typo3-cms-scripts": [
            "typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure",
            "typo3cms install:generatepackagestates"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@typo3-cms-scripts"
        ]
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
[Screenshot of my Page TS Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrqo5.png)
As you can see I cannot write sth into it like you can. I also installed the news extension as you did.
But what exactly do you mean by "and updating the database by the wizard in the install-tool"?
I just went into the install tool > Maintenace > Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache and to the "Analyze Database Structure". Both worked fine, but still the Page TS Config panel wasn't editable to me. So how do I update the database in the install tool?

And yes we are talking about the same Page TS Config panel within the "List" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your own account to "Manage System Maintainers" in "Admin Tools" -> "Settings".

If that's not possible, you can add it manually in the file  `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`:

```
return [
    'BE' => [
        ...
    ],
    ...
    'SYS' => [
        ...
        'systemLogLevel' => 2,
        'systemMaintainers' => [
            54,
        ],
    ],
];
```

In the line where you see `54` replace the `54` with the uid of your admin-account. If `systemMaintainers` is missing completely, just add it like you see it in the code above.

If you have to do it manually in the file you've to clear the cache manually perhaps too:
Just delete everything inside `typo3temp\var\cache`.

**EDIT**
After reading your question again and the comments here I got doubts that we're talking about the same field. I marked the field where you can write in the screenshot below with some text:

[image]

In the other fields above you can't write, but only (de)select if some extensions provide some special files to be shown in that fields.

After having installed `news` with

```
composer require georgringer/news
```

and updating the database by the wizard in the install-tool the page is looking like this:

[image]

If you click on the paper-basket between the white fields the item of the left field is going in the right field, if you click on it then, it's going to the left field again.

But for writing, it's still the field in the bottom ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that did not work. I added my admin and a freshly set up backend use account to "Admin Tools" > "Setting" > "Manage System Maintainers" and I checked manually if the UId in the typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php matched my backend user id (which it did). Then I also deleted the typo3temp\var\cache as suggested. 
Still no luck.
But I figured that I can edit the Page TS Config in the phpmyadmin database panel...So I will try that now. 
Wish me luck that I don't mess up my backend :D :D
And thank you again for your reply!

Comment: Maybe add the composer.json to your question, could be that there is missing something

Comment: just added my composer.json.

For anyone who thought (like me^^) you can edit the Page TS Config in the phpmyadmin panel...no you cannot, I tried it. The changes from the phpmyadmin are not shown in the Typo3 Backend Pages TS Config.

Comment: I installed a new instance with your composer file and have no problem using the PageTS field. I suspect some file(s) like JavaScript or CSS are not loaded, perhaps even the page itself not completely. Can you check that in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: If you still encounter problems, perhaps post a screenshot to explain it more.

Comment: Hey @Scrat99, any feedback on this?

Comment: Hello, David, sorry for my late response. 
I cannot add anything into my page ts config. But I managed to install the gridelements extension and I think this extension doesn't allow the user to edit the page tsconfig in the first place. Which would make sense because we would have the backend layout wizard, where you can adjust the columns, right? ^^

I also realized that the opportunity to allow certain content elments in the backend layout columns only comes when the gridelements extension is installed. Im a beginner at Typo3 since this is my first cms project ever :D

Comment: okay, update: For some reson it works now! :D Thank you for your help! :)